# Transition height, get bigger to 2 sides

Tags: html, css

I just made a text window which gets bigger if you `hover` over it (with a `transition` that adds more `height`). It basically "drops" down to the bottom and pushes away the other text. Is there any way I can make it "drop" to the bottom by 50% and "climb" up by 50%?

```css
#tcontent {
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
#mcontent {
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  transition: height 0.5s ease;
}
#bcontent {
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
#mcontent:hover {
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="tcontent">
  </div>
  <div id="mcontent">
  </div>
  <div id="bcontent">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Gofilord http://jsfiddle.net/21kvgbxw/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is awkward through conventional means as content flows from left to right, top to bottom and `#mcontent` needs space to move into above. However, this can be achieved by using `flexbox`.

- Add `#main` with `display: flex;` to get its children to use the `flexbox` model
- Add `flex-direction: column;` to `#main` to make the children order from top to bottom
- Add `height: 550px;` to `#main` to make it as high as the three children will be when `#mcontent` is expanded
- Add `justify-content: center;` to `#main` to center the children in the middle

The principle behind it is that the elements are set to always be in the middle of `#main`. When `#mcontent` grows, it pushes `#tcontent` up and `#bcontent` because they have space to move into. As they are set to be centered `#mcontent` will stay in the middle.

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 550px;
  justify-content: center;
}
#tcontent {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
#mcontent {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 150px;
  transition: height 0.5s ease;
  width: 100%;
}
#mcontent:hover {
  height: 250px;
}
#bcontent {
  background-color: green;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="tcontent"></div>
  <div id="mcontent"></div>
  <div id="bcontent"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i do absolutely not understand what this thing does but whatever, it works amazingly well! Thank you a lot, really appreciate it

Comment: @Econ No problem. If there is anything in particular you don't understand please let me know and I'll try to help.

Comment: thank you. there is actually already a thing wich i am not sure about if you can help me. If i use now for the hover effect height:100% instead of for example 250px; the transition doesn't work.... it's just instantly jumping. You got  quick idea how to fix this if it's even possible to be fixed :D?

Comment: @Econ It seems to work for me https://jsfiddle.net/johxqqy2/, does the fiddle work for you? You may need to raise a new question!

Comment: yes your fidle worked for me. Here's mine http://jsfiddle.net/xbpqphzz/ i try to get it working with the help of your fidle, otherways i will open up a new question. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The reason the `div` pushes and moves down is the default behavior of CSS `height` is to increase the height to the bottom. You can use a new CSS3 feature:  **Transformation** . Precisely, the `scale()` function.

### CSS:

Add these lines to your style

```
#mcontent {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#mcontent:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1, 1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1.2);
  transform: scale(1, 1.2);
  height: 185px;
}
```

Also, in your stylesheet you're using multiple `height` properties together, in a single block. That's not a good practice, try cleaning those up.

```
#mcontent {
  height: 30px; /* this line is not necessary */
  height: 150px; /* as this line overrides the first one */
}
```

Comment: Thats a great thing thanks i will keep it in mind but it's actually not what i am looking for. This just makes the text pop out, but i want the text to push the other texts more to the top/bottom. and the width should stay the same

Comment: yeah, hover over the div in the middle. Its acting a "bit" weird... welll it's actually fun to watch haha... cheking your edit now! (cheked it, still acts weird)

Comment: @Econ, Oops! Sorry, try my latest answer with `scale(1, 2);`.

Comment: sadly this is just hovering over the other 2 divs and i need the upper and the lower div to be pushed away :/

Comment: @Econ `scale(1, 1.2);`.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/99uvom23/).

I used `margin-top: -50px;` and animated the margin as well. Used margin for the top expansion and let the bottom expansion still make the div below slide.

**EDITED CSS**

```
#mcontent {
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    transition: height 0.5s ease, margin-top 0.5s ease;
}

#mcontent:hover {
    height: 250px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Comment: That's nice but by adding the second line of transition you cancel the `height` transition. You should just transition all elements. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99uvom23/1/).

Comment: I edited my answer for multiple transition. I believe that adding transition: all is not advisable since there might be styles that is not intended to be animated.

Comment: @Gofilord aaahhh that's so close to what i want thanks, i alrdy aprecciate it a lot. But now the middle div is going ABOVE the top div and covers a part of it... and it should push it away...

Comment: @Econ Does the effect have to occur when hovering over `#mcontent`? Can it occur when hovering over the entire `#main`?

Comment: @Gofilord no it has to occure seperately for the div when you hover over it

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform: scale(1,2);` as shown in the snippet.

In your css you set `height` multiple times, try to avoid this. Also in the `:hover` declaration you only need to specify the parameters who change. So in this case only `transform`.

```css
#tcontent {
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
#mcontent {
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#bcontent {
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
#mcontent:hover {
  transform: scale(1,2)
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="tcontent">
  </div>
  <div id="mcontent">
  </div>
  <div id="bcontent">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can allow the effect to occur when hovering over `#main` and not just `#mcontent`, this works perfectly:

```
#main > div {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#tcontent {
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
#mcontent {
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    /* new */
    position: relative;
}
#bcontent {
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#main:hover #mcontent {
    height: 250px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}

#main:hover #tcontent {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
}
```

[Fiddle demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/99uvom23/4/)